# Does $\mathbf{W}^H\mathbf{W}=\mathbf{I}$ imply $\mathbf{WW}^H=\mathbf{I}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Does $\mathbf{W}^H\mathbf{W}=\mathbf{I}$ imply $\mathbf{WW}^H=\mathbf{I}$?

Note: $\mathbf{W}$ is a square complex constant matrix, $\mathbf{W}^H$ is the conjugate transpose of $\mathbf{W}$, and $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are square matrices and $AB = I$ then $BA = I$.

Edit: here's a proof.  Assume $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ matrices with entries in a field $F$, and that $AB = I$.  We wish to show that $BA = I$.

The range of $A$ is all of $F^n$, so the rank of $A$ is $n$.  By the rank-nullity theorem, $N(A) = \{0\}$.

For any $x \in F^n$,
\begin{align}
A(BAx) &= (AB) Ax \\
&= A x .
\end{align}
It follows that $BAx = x$ for all $x \in F^n$, which shows that $BA = I$.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, if $A$ and $B$ are *finite* etc.  :-)

Comment: @littleO : I confess I have never read a proof of this before.  I'd always assumed the proof was difficult and messy.  Thanks.  (Now I must read the proof of the rank-nullity theorem and see if _that_ is difficult and messy.)

Comment: @StefanSmith For the rank-nullity theorem, given an $m \times n$ matrix $M$ with entries in a field $F$, we just start with a basis $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$ of $N(M)$ and extend it to a basis $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k,v_{k+1},\ldots, v_n \}$ of $F^n$.  The vectors $Mv_{k+1},\ldots, M v_{n}$ form a basis of $R(M)$.  We see that $\text{dim } N(M) + \text{dim } R(M) = n$.